# Parametro HttpGet não é detectado

Tags: c#, angularjs, http

Boa tarde pessoal, não sei o por que meu parâmetro não é reconhecido, podem me ajudar? O valor não chega no c# mas esta presente no angular
c#

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("carregarUsuarioPorId")]
public HttpResponseMessage BuscarUsuarioPorId()
{
        try
        {
            WSS_RetornoListaDTO<Usuario> wss = new WSS_RetornoListaDTO<Usuario>();

            int idUser = 0;

            var req = Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();

            if (req != null)
            {
                foreach (var parameter in req)
                {
                    if (parameter.Key.Equals("id"))
                        idUser = int.Parse(parameter.Value.ToString());
                }
            }

            usuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAO();
            wss.resultado = usuarioDAO.BuscarUsuarioPorId(idUser);
            if (wss.resultado.Count > 0)
            {
                wss.codRetorno = 200;
                wss.msgRetorno = "Sucesso";

                return Request.CreateResponse<WSS_RetornoListaDTO<Usuario>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, wss);
            }
            else
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, "Usuario não localizado");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "ERRO - " + e.Message);
        }
}
```

chamada  do parametro:

```
getUserPorId: function (idUser) {
    var id = [];
    id[0] = idUser;
    return 
    $http.get('http://localhost:61223/usuario/carregarUsuarioPorId',id)
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
      });
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na chamada

```
public HttpResponseMessage BuscarUsuarioPorId()
```

não existe o parametro. A api não vai reconhecer, pq provavelmente seu RouteConfig está dizendo que id é opcional. Coloque desta forma

```
public HttpResponseMessage BuscarUsuarioPorId(int id)
```

e você vai economizar todo este código boilerplate

```
var req = Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();

if (req != null)
{
    foreach (var parameter in req)
    {
        if (parameter.Key.Equals("id"))
            idUser = int.Parse(parameter.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Só complementando, é sempre interessante colocar o parâmetro na rota também: `[Route("carregarUsuarioPorId/{id:int:min(1)}")]` assim eu posso restringir com constraint o que é o meu valor na URL.

Answer (score 1):

Para passar parâmetros na `query` do `$http#get` você deve passar o objeto `config` como segundo parâmetro:

```
var params = {};

params.id = id;

$http.get('http://localhost:61223/usuario/carregarUsuarioPorId', {params: params}).then(function(response) {
  return response.data;
});
```